# mat-dialog not filling screen - Angular

Tags: css, angular, angular-material

I have an image carousel inside a mat-dialog. It doesn't really matter what component I feed the mat-dialog. They never fill the screen so I don't think it's the specific component inside mat-dialog that's the issue.

[image]

I want it to fill the width 100% and `height:auto` to make the image fit correctly, but it doesn't seem to work and I have no idea why.

```
  openImageGalleryMobile(images) {
    const imageDialogRef = this.dialog.open(ImageCarouselComponent, {
      panelClass: "matdialogStyle",
      data: { images: images},
      height: 'auto',
      width: '100%',
    });

    imageDialogRef
      .afterClosed()
      .pipe(takeUntil(this.destroy))
      .subscribe(result => { });
  }
```

```
<div id="imageSlideshow">

  <ngb-carousel *ngIf="images">
    <ng-template ngbSlide *ngFor="let image of images">
      <img src='{{image}}' alt="Random first side">

    </ng-template>

  </ngb-carousel>



</div>
```

I tried adding `.matdialogStyle` as a new unaltered css class, but issue is still there. I tried setting the width to 100% from component css file or styles.css file using `matdialogStyle` css class, but it never updates.  I appreciate the help!

Comment: Are you getting any error in console. Can you please create stackblitz instance replicating your issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can you try :

```
{
  panelClass: "matdialogStyle",
  data: { images: images},
  height: 'auto',
  minWidth: '100%',
}
```

and you can add for height 100% :

```
minHeight: '100vh'
```

Comment: That didn't work. The backdrop filled the height of the screen, but I did manage to center it by removing height and minWidth and minHeight. https://postimg.cc/PLh5h6PD  I just can't figure out how to get it to fill more of the screen

Comment: and with delete "panelClass: "matdialogStyle". Just with minWidth: '100%' work with me...

Comment: Looks much better now. Thanks for the help! https://postimg.cc/9z4by1QZ